# How to run Karate tests in Scala Project

Tags: scala, karate

I included karate dependencies in my build.sbt file, which folder structure do I add my karate feature file and how do I test in a Scala Play project?
Is there any example for Scala or Play application testing for Karate. basically I want to test my Graphql Scala backend endpoints.
For eg: I used this for cucumber testing and it works fine, https://github.com/sbt/sbt-cucumber

I tried running test command in set shell

My build.sbt has the following,
`"com.intuit.karate" % "karate-core" % "0.9.3"`

And which folder structure to use to place my feature file and how to run the scala tests?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have one yet - but maybe you can be the one to contribute or blog about an example.

You can refer to the work done for Gradle, see this: [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/build.gradle).

Other than that, the only hint I have is some work done for the Karate Gatling integration, which uses Scala a little: [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-gatling/build.gradle).